# Почему сохраняется телефон как username в сохраненных паролях Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, регистрация

Что необходимо сделать чтобы сохранялся е-мейл а не телефон при регистрации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нунжо что бы поля для авторизации имели атрибуты `name="login"` или `name="email"` + `autocomplete="on"`. Для пароля соответственно `type="password"`. Поля должны быть в одной форме. Тогда браузер определит их как логин и пароль. А у телефона можно указать `autocomplete="off"`